# Pow(x,n) Leetcode - Recursion Doesnt Work

Tags: javascript, typescript, recursion

I've been looking at this output for so long and I don't know why it's not correct...
The correct answer is **1.13074** but I'm getting **1.06336** which is incorrect. Does anyone see the flaw in this?

I'm implementing pow(x,n) which returns x^n but uses the principle of (x^n)^m = x^n*m to make runtime quicker.

Code

```
function getMiddleFactors(n: number): number[] {
    const factors = [];
    for(let i = 1; i <= n; i=i+1) {
        if(n%i===0) {
            factors.push(i);
        }
    }

    return [factors[Math.floor(factors.length/2) - 1], factors[Math.floor(factors.length/2)]]
}

function myPow(x: number, n: number): number {
    let answer = 1;
    const negative = n < 0;

    if(negative) {
        n = -n;
    }

    if(n < 20) {
        for(let i = 0; i < n; i=i+1) {
            answer = answer * x;
        }
    } else {
        const factors = getMiddleFactors(n);
        console.log(`Got the factors: ${factors}`)
       
        const inner = myPow(x, factors[0]);
        console.log(`Got the inner number ${x}^${factors[0]}: ${inner}`);

        answer = myPow(inner,factors[1]);
        console.log(`Got the answer for ${x}^${n} (${inner}^${factors[1]}): ${answer}`);
    }
    
    if(negative) {
        answer = 1/answer;
    }

    return answer
};
```

Output

```
Got the factors: 16,32
Got the inner number 1.00012^16: 1.0019217289680562
Got the factors: 4,8
Got the inner number 1.0019217289680562^4: 1.0077091025273281
Got the answer for 1.0019217289680562^32 (1.0077091025273281^8): 1.0633627729389192
Got the answer for 1.00012^1024 (1.0019217289680562^32): 1.0633627729389192
```

Comment: Maybe you should use exponentiation by squaring instead (which is O(log2 n)), which is probably faster than this method since you don't have to compute the factors?

Comment: Oh, even with exponentiation by squaring I get the same answer: https://tsplay.dev/NlDjlN - I also tried using BigInt to see if it was a floating point accuracy issue... same answer...

Answer (score 0):

The problem appears to be that you don't distinguish between an *even* number of factors (where you code should work) and *odd* number of factors (where it doesn't)  The number 1024 has an odd number of factors (2, 4, 8, 16, **32**, 64, 128, 256, 512) as 32 is its *square root* and used twice.  (Not 16 and 32.)

1.00012 ^ 1024

= 1.00012 ^ (32 * 32)

= (1.00012 ^ 32) ^ 32

= (1.00012 ^ (4 * 8)) ^ 32

= ((1.00012 ^ 4) ^ 8) ^ 32

= ((1.00012 ^ 4) ^ 8) ^ (4 * 8)

= ((((1.00012 ^ 4) ^ 8) ^ 4) ^ 8)